# Unexpected behavior of ComplexityFunction

Tags: simplifying-expressions, warning-messages, built-in-symbols

As far as I know, the complexity must be a positive value. But I get such example:

```
Reap[FullSimplify[ArcSin[Cos[x]], 0 <= x <= 1, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (Sow[-LeafCount[#] + 
       Count[#, _Cos, {0, Infinity}]*100] &)]]
```

> {1/2 (Pi-2
>   x),{{97,98,-1,-1,98,98,98,98,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,97,89,89,89,89,89,89,89,89,89,89,89,93,93,93,93,93,93,95,95,95,97,-1,-1,-1,-3,-3,-3,-3,-1,-1,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-5,-5,-5,-5,-9,-9,-9,-9,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-1,-1,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-5,-5,-5,-5,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-1,-1,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-5,-5,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9,-9}}}

Well, since the negative value works, why I can't change the `100` to `2`? Such as:

```
Reap[FullSimplify[ArcSin[Cos[x]], 0 <= x <= 1, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (Sow[-LeafCount[#] + 
       Count[#, _Cos, {0, Infinity}]*2] &)]]
```

I will get some error information (`$RecursionLimit::reclim`).

---

## Update for [george2079's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133053/unexpected-behavior-of-complexityfunction?noredirect=1#comment358981_133053):

I made a variable `tem` to collect the value in intermediate caculation:

```
tem = <||>;
cache := (AssociateTo[tem, # -> #]; #) &
FullSimplify[ArcSin[Cos[x]], 0 <= x <= 1, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (cache[100 - LeafCount[#]] &)]
```

This code will give some error information:
[image]

You cannot finish the calculation normally. Click the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> after a certain time. Then you will get some value producing in intermediate caculation.

```
Counts[Sign[Values[tem]]]
```

> <|1->83,-1->288,0->1|>

Of course, you can get a same case by my original example. But this case is more obvious those value producing in intermediate caculation is not all of negtive.

Comment: just a wag but i suppose in the second case it is always negative.

Comment: @george2079 I couldn't understand the complexity of a expression is negative.

Comment: you should show the error message.  What are you trying to accomplish anyway?

Comment: @george2079 I have updated about what you thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First measuring "complexity" with a negative leaf count means that `Simplify` will prefer expressions with more leaves. If in a given situation there are always standard transformations that lead to more leaves, then the "simplification" process will never finish.

I believe errors arise because with a coefficient of `2` or less, the code leads to trigonometric identities being applied that make the expressions have more leaves.  Probably there are always identities that can make them have more leaves. A higher coefficient puts a stop to ones with `Cos[]`, which happens to put a stop to the process.

Try this to see only a few hundred steps:

```
TimeConstrained[
 Reap[FullSimplify[ArcSin[Cos[x]], 0 <= x <= 1, 
   ComplexityFunction -> (Sow[
       Print[#]; -LeafCount[#] + Count[#, _Cos, {0, Infinity}]*2] &)]],
 0.1]
```

I think `2` is the magic number because

```
LeafCount[Cos[x]]
(*  2  *)
```

With a coefficient `3`, it finishes:

```
Reap[FullSimplify[ArcSin[Cos[x]], 0 <= x <= 1, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (Sow[-LeafCount[#] + 
       Count[#, _Cos, {0, Infinity}]*3] &)]]
(*
{1/2 (π - 2 x),
 {{0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   ...
   -9, -9, -9}}}
*)
```

Comment: 1)Have you try to change that `2` to `1` or other small number?.2)Have you seen my new update? the `2` go away. :-)

Comment: @yode Isn't the explanation obviously the same? Lowering it (to zero) makes things worse!

Comment: I get your point.